# What purpose would a flashing between the studwork baseplate and a concrete slab serve?

Tags: insulation, slab, timber-framing

I have seen and read online that the baseplate is usually fixed directly to the edge of the slab. However, I also saw a passive house video on YouTube where the builder placed a rubber gasket under the baseplate and sealed both sides with caulk to prevent any leakage of air under the baseplate.

I told my builder, who has almost 50 years experience, about the gasket but he couldn't find a supplier so instead he suggested running a few beads of silicone before the baseplate was put in place.

Unfortunately that builder was injured and is now not working while he recovers. I found a new builder with almost 25 years experience but he says that he always installs a flashing under the baseplate and down the side of the slab. He insists that it somehow prevents moisture ingress, gives extra protection against termites and prevents air exchange. I suppose it might work as a covering for the slab edge to keep off any rain that gets past the exterior cladding but how would it work with the baseplate to make an air seal?

Comment: I am used to seeing 2 continuous beads of caulk, but I'm not a framer.

Comment: Don't know where in the world you are, as you don't say, but in the USA sill seal foam strip is normal, standard and can be found at any builder's supply.

Comment: "Termite shield flashing" is normally installed in that position, yes.